# Binding UITableViewCell with ViewModel and updating the ViewController ViewModel?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewmodel, viewcontroller

I have registed `viewModels` for every `UITableViewCell`. I update `viewModel` of cell with user interactions. As the `viewController` contains the array of `viewModel` and allocates the viewModel on `cellForRowAt`. I need to reload the cell. How can i update the array of viewModel. Or do i need to?

Please ask if i am not able to communicate the issue.

**How can i update the viewModel array in viewController or do i need to?**

Comment: what user interactions you are taking?

Comment: button touchUpInside

Comment: please share your code of `cellForRowAt` and `tableViewCell` Class

Comment: do you know protocols and delegates? They will be useful here

Comment: Yeah. but i don't want delegates for every cell. Need some lean solution. KVO maybe

Comment: okay let me think

Comment: Ever used MVVM? know the concept of boxing?

Comment: @sanjaykmwt not aware of boxing

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a reusable cell in the tableView, the method: tableView.realodData() could help you.
Write it down after each time you're updating the array